# MATLAB - Set title of a plot

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I have this error when i try to set the title of my plot :

```
Error using matlab.graphics.axis.Axes/set
While setting the 'Title' property of 'Axes':
Value must be 'matlab.graphics.primitive.Text'.
```

What I don't understand is that I followed that tutorial : [mathworks creating plots](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/add-title-axis-labels-and-legend-to-graph.html)

There is my code :

```
set(handles.axes3,'Title','Red Fluorescence','xLim',[1 (handles.gap*2)],'yLim',[handles.YminR handles.YmaxR]);
```

Thank you !

Comment: can you provide the code that generated your figure so we can re-create the problem?

Comment: As stated in the [documentation](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes-properties.html#zmw57dd0e52818), the `Title` property of an `axes` element is not a String, but a Text object. (That's what the error says). A call to `set(handles.axes3.Title,'String','Red Fluorescence,...)` should do the work

Comment: Thank you ! it works perfectly.

Comment: The link at @BillBokeey's comment is broken : [new link](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.axis.axes-properties.html?searchHighlight=axes&s_tid=srchtitle#budumk7-Title)